# UI5 - how to run Karma without allTests file, running all tests from the folder

Tags: unit-testing, sapui5, karma-runner

I am currently preparing some unit tests POC for out UI5 web application. To run them, we would like to use **Karma runner**. In its installation guide, I see this

```
All tests should be listed in specific files. You can, for example, collect all unit tests in an allTests.js file. With the help of this file, Karma can find all tests that belong to specific modules or components.

    client: {
      openui5: {
        tests: [
          'test/unit/allTests',
          'test/integration/AllJourneys'
```

Using the `allTests.js` file, I am indeed able to execute unit tests. However, now I am thinking if its absolutely necessary to use this `allTests.js` file - because now, when we add new .js test to our test scope, we also need to add its path to the `allTests.js` file which seems like the extra work (and source of problem if its forgotten).

I think much better would be if all `.js` files from the `"test/unit"` path were **executed by Karma without the need to collect them all in a single file**. However, I haven't found online any way to do it and my experiments are failing so far. For example, I deleted `openui5/tests` section of the configuration file and tried to define loaded tests in `files` section like this

```
files: ['https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.65.1/resources/sap-ui-core.js', 'test/unit/*.js'],
```

Could someone advise? Is it possible to bypass `allTests.js` file and if yes, how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: I dont know if this is possible (and would be interested if it is :p). For our project we have a watch script that generates the allTests.js automatically on file change / add / remove. It works like a charm but is not as clean as what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that could actually also help, much better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we did as Ji aSH recommended - at the start of each test run, we run a script that collects the names of all .js files in the test/unit folder and creates allTests.js file from them. Like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// List all files in a directory in Node.js recursively in a synchronous fashion
const walkSync = function (dir, filelist) {

    if (dir[dir.length - 1] != path.sep) dir = dir.concat(path.sep)

    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    filelist = filelist || [];
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        if (fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory()) {
            filelist = walkSync(path.join(dir, file), filelist);
        }
        else {
            if (path.extname(file) === '.js' && path.basename(file) !== 'allTests.js') {
                const filePath = `\n    '${dir}${path.basename(file, '.js')}'`;
                filelist.push(filePath.replace('webapp', path.join('xxx', 'xxxxl')));
            }
        }
    });
    return filelist;
};

const testFiles = walkSync(path.join('webapp', 'test', 'unit'), null);
const fileContent = `sap.ui.define([${testFiles},\n], () => { 'use strict'; });\n`;

fs.writeFileSync(path.join('webapp', 'test', 'unit', 'allTests.js'), fileContent);
```